# How to I make jumping look realistic and making it so that when I use W button I jump once not continuously ascending?

Tags: javascript, game-physics

I wont it to look realistic when jumping and I need some help with the controls. When pressing when Pressing the W key i only want it to activate once not keep ascending.

Heres my jsfiddle: 
        `https://jsfiddle.net/Lpn7sokg/`

```
  this.gravity = 0.5;   this.gravitySpeed = 0;
```

I have tried messing around with these for a better looking jump but nothings is working.

Comment: Maybe you could use a Physics Javascript library
See http://www.wellcaffeinated.net/PhysicsJS

Comment: Set the vertical velocity to the jump speed only if the player is touching the ground; once in mid-air, use the [basic equations of motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_of_motion#Constant_translational_acceleration_in_a_straight_line) to update the position.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you need to keep track of when the button is pressed and when it is released so that on each tick of the game you can determine its current state (i.e., pressed or not).

Then, you also need decide on how jumping works in your game. For example, many platformer games (unlike real life) allow the character to jump higher the longer button is pressed... but only up to a point.  If you want this kind of mechanic, you might keep a countdown of how many ticks the jump button has been down, and during each tick that the countdown is above zero, add a little to the character's altitude.  Once the countdown expires, ignore the state of the jump button until the character hits the ground again.